# mysql select two different queries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, scripting

I'm looking for help with a formula. I'm looking for how to do two separate SELECT queries, but without merging them so.

```
SELECT basetype from table1 where name="test";
**SELECT itemid from table2 where itemid="5";**
```

I want the query to display basetype as a column and itemid as another column. Short version is two selects in one query displaying results. Data doesn't have to match between the tables.

EDIT: I screwed up. It's two separate tables. The results I want is basically this.

No union.

```
BASETYPE | ITEMID
    1    |   5
```

Comment: Could you add some sample input/desired result? I can't quite figure out what you're looking for.

Comment: are you looking for a UNION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want this:

```
select rn, max(basetype) as basetype, max(itemid) as itemid
from ((SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 as rn, basetype, NULL as itemid
       from table1 cross join
            (select @rn := 0) var
       where name = 'test'
      ) union all
      (SELECT @rn2 := @rn2 + 1, NULL, itemid
       from table2 cross join
            (select @rn2 := 0) var
       where itemid = '5'
      )
     ) t
group by rn;
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want to initialize @rn in both subqueries.

Comment: @MarcusAdams . . . That is sooo true.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with union :

```
 SELECT basetype from table1 where name="test"
 union 
 SELECT itemid  as basetype from table1 where itemid="5";
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create subqueries.

```
SELECT a.basetype, b.itemid FROM
(SELECT basetype from table1 where name="test") a,
(SELECT itemid from table1 where itemid="5") b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT basetype, itemid
 FROM table1
 where table1.name="test" AND table1.itemid="5";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) or using [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) (also known as subselects).
I think you're looking for UNION.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```